# Spring define batch job at runtime

Tags: java, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-batch

I am working on Spring-mvc application.

I have a requirement of scheduling batch job at runtime

For now I am concentrating on `creating batch job at runtime`.

I am taking example from [**this**](http://java.dzone.com/articles/chunk-oriented-processing).

In the example, following entry is in xml file

```
<!-- Failed Step Tasklet Declaration -->
<bean id="failedStepTasklet" class="com.onlinetechvision.tasklet.FailedStepTasklet">
    <property name="taskResult"  value="Error occurred!" />
</bean>

<batch:job id="secondJob">
    <batch:step id="firstFailedStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="failedStepTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

My requirement is to create batch job and batch step at runtime. There can be multiple batch job as well as multiple batch steps in each job.

Can any one please help me, how to configure at runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: Create the actual flow or just instanciate the pre-defined job?

Comment: @MichaelMinella, I can pre-define tasklet, but I can not pre-define jobs. So I want to create `batch:job` and `batch:step` at runtime.